# Perl explicit package in nested loops

Tags: perl

I declared this array:

```
my @array
```

And in this code block...

```
for (my $i=0; $i<$j; $i++) {

      do {
              // stdout operations
      } while (! ($arr != 1 ));
}
```

The error is specifically in the `} while (! ($arr != 1 ));` line.

Here's the specific error:
*Global symbol "$arr" requires explicit package name at exer4bernal.pl line 71.*

Why do I have this problem in 2 levels of nested loops? I never had this in only 1 level. What should I change to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: At which line u have declared `$arr` like `my $arr`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with loops. It seems that the `$var` variable is undeclared. Where is the line `my $arr`?

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing is totally unrelated to nesting of loop. What Perl is trying to tell you is that it doesn't know about the `$arr` variable. Did you mean `@array` or `$#array`?

Answer (score -2):

Normally, you shouldn't be using `do...while` blocks. What is `$arr`? Where is that value declared? Where is it changed in your `while loop`? What is `$j`?

Actually, what are you trying to do with a double loop? This is usually considered bad programming because when you move from processing `x` elements to `y` elements, you increase your processing time by `y`<sup>`2`</sup>`- (x * y)`;

Maybe this is more what you mean?

```
for my $index ( (0..$#array) ) {
    next if $array[$index] = 1;
    ...
}
```

Note I got rid of that ugly *C Style* for loop and replaced it with one that's easier to understand.

Comment: I think your point about do-while loops needs some clarification. Should they always be avoided? Or here? And why?

Comment: I have never heard of nested loops being considered bad programming.

Comment: @Borodin There are sometimes when nested loops are necessary, but they scale very, very poorly. if it takes 1 second to process 100 items, it will 4 seconds to process 200 items, and 9 seconds to process 300 items. Many times, nested loops are a sign that you need to rethink your strategy.

Comment: @innaM Page #123 of [Damian Conway's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damian_Conway) book _[Perl Best Practices_](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596001735.do): _"Don't use do...while loops"_. I wouldn't necessarily do a blanket condemnation of them, but I can't think of the last time I used them.

Comment: @DavidW.: You appear not to know what you are talking about. The form of the code will follow the structure of the data, and nested data will produce nested code. Only a very special sort of algorithm will produce square-law response times; ordinarily speed of response is linear - nested or not.

Comment: @Borodin - It's not a _special_ sort algorithm that causes square-law response times. It's the basic bubble sort taught in programming 101. The reason the bubble sort is so inefficient is that it uses a double nested loop. One of the problems is that the OP never clarified what the inner loop is doing or how it gets incremented. Nor, have we seen any feedback from the OP. My assumption (because I've seen many beginners do this) is that the OP probably meant an `if` statement.